# NHibernate query many to many

Tags: nhibernate, model-associations

I have an odd requirement. Simplified, I have a table of products and a table of languages. Each product contains a description which is a string, in English. In my application, I need to show the description in one of 15 languages determined by the user. Each product includes an `IDictionary<Language, String>` that contains the localized descriptions, indexed by language. All products have an English description, but not all products are translated into all 15 languages at a point in time.

The odd requirement is this: for a given product, if the translated product description does not exist in the user's language, fallback to English.

As stated, this may not seem so odd, but I'm struggling with to map this.  After several false starts, I've created a view in SQL that basically creates a cross join (Cartesian product) of `ProductId` and `LanguageId` and joins twice with the translation table, once for all translations and once with a subquery in English.  From this, I extract a translation using COALESCE() to get a translation for each combination of product and language code, in English if necessary.  So basically the columns in this view are `ProductId`, `LanguageId` and `Translation`.

How would I map this? Most importantly, how do I query this? I only need to be able to read data from this view.

Clearly this is a bit complex.  Is there a better way?

Comment: It would help if you actually accept the answers provided to you, as it will help others help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this do?

```
<class name="Product" table="products">
  <id name="Id">  
    <generator class="native"/>  
  </id>  
  <property name="Description" />

  <map name="LocalizedDescriptions" table="descriptions">
    <key column="product_id"/>  
    <index column="language" type="String" />  
    <element column="description" type="String" />  
  </map>
</class>
```

Regarding the case there is no description in the user language, just check whether the entry is in the dictionary and that's it.

```
public string GetDescription(string language)
{
    return LocalizedDescriptions.ContainsKey(language) ? LocalizedDescriptions[language] : Description;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are doing and I think I may have caused some confusion.  The "description" as part of the product is just a brief description that is used by administrators to distinguish one product from another.  The fallback value to display to the end user is actually in the "descriptions" in a row with English language.

Comment: OK, but the idea remains the same. Instead of the description used by administrators just return the description in English from the "descriptions".

Comment: OK.  As I mentioned, this was a simplified statement of the problem, but your solution works.  Where I was struggling was to implement this everywhere it was needed.  I ended up creating a helper to encapsulate the logic similar to what you recommend and this is now working everywhere.